# Deriving $-nE\left[\frac{\partial ^2\ln\left(f\left(X\right)\right)}{\partial \theta ^2}\right]$

Tags: probability, statistics

The information about θ in a random sample of size n is also given by
$$-nE\left[\frac{\partial ^2\ln\left(f_\theta\left(X\right)\right)}{\partial \theta ^2}\right]$$

where $f_\theta(x)$ is the value of the population density at x, provided that the extremes of the region for which $f_\theta(x)$ is not equal to 0 do not depend on θ. The derivation of this formula takes the following steps:

Differentiating the expressions on both sides of
$$\int f_\theta\left(x\right)dx=1$$
with respect to $\theta$, show that
$$\int \frac{\partial \ln\left(f_\theta\left(x\right)\right)}{\partial \theta }\left(f_\theta\left(x\right)\right)dx=0$$
by interchanging the order of integration and differentiation.

Differentiating again with respect to θ, show that
$$E\left[\left(\frac{\partial \ln\left(f_\theta\left(X\right)\right)}{\partial \theta }\right)^2\right]=-E\left[\frac{\partial ^2\ln\left(f_\theta\left(X\right)\right)}{\partial \theta ^2}\right]$$

I'm a little confused about what the question is asking. I am not sure how the $\ln$ comes in, in the first part and then how I relate that to the second part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln(f_\theta(x))=\frac{1}{f_\theta(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f_\theta(x)$$
and so,
$$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln(f_\theta(x))\Big) f_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{f_\theta(x)}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f_\theta(x)\Big) f_\theta (x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f_\theta(x)$$

So, assuming that he order of differentiation and integration can be change one has, for the first step,

$$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\int_R f_\theta(x)\,dx=\int_R\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} f_\theta(x)\,dx=\int_R \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln(f_\theta(x))\Big) f_\theta(x)\,dx=\mathbb{E}_\theta\Big[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln(f_\theta(X))\Big]
$$

where the last identity follows  from the definition of expectation of functions with respect to probability measures with densities, namely
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[g(X)]=\int_R g(x) f_\theta(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense! So then I would differentiate again but I don't understand how the expectation comes in?

Comment: I am just showing the derivation process inside the expectation (assuming one can exchange the order of differentiation and expectation). I expanded my explanation just now.